# How am I able to have multiple css animations on the same page, using the same spritesheet?

Tags: css, html

I cannot figure out how to use the same spritesheet with multiple sprites (4 sprites per monster animation). I thought putting them in different div IDs would work but it doesn't seem to.

Also, the tutorial I used was many years old - is all of the `-webkit -moz -ms -o` necessary anymore, instead of just using `@keyframes` and `animation`? Or is there a better way of doing it? Would cut down on a lot of time if it weren't needed as I have many many sprites I will be working on.

```css
#monster {
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/423540996098228245/494950824963866635/16x16.png");
  -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(4) infinite;
  -moz-animation: play .8s steps(4) infinite;
  -ms-animation: play .8s steps(4) infinite;
  -o-animation: play .8s steps(4) infinite;
  animation: play .8s steps(4) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -360px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -360px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -360px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -360px;
  }
}

@keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -360px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="monster"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, it's alright to have [unprefixed CSS animations](https://caniuse.com/#search=animation)

Each sprite frame is 90x90px, so you multiply the frame size by the amount of frames to figure out how much to translate the animation by.
To be able to scale each monster you will need to translate the background by percentages, for that you need to know the full length of the spritesheet which is 16849px. This gives you the translation percentage: `translation in px / spritesheet length * 100 = translation percentage` eg (rough pseudo code follows):

**First animation:**
$sprite_size: 90px;
$frames: 4;
90*4=360
starts at 0, goes to -360
percentage to translate = 360/16849*100=2.136625319

**Second animation:**
$start_pos: 360;
$translate_length: 90*4=360;
$start_pos+$translate_length = 720
starts at -360, goes to -720

Consider using [SCSS or SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) to help you easily calculate the animations.

```css
.monster {
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/423540996098228245/494950824963866635/16x16.png");
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.monster--pixie {
  animation: idle_pixie .8s steps(4) infinite;
}

.monster--fairy {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: idle_fairy .8s steps(4) infinite;
}

/*
Total sprite length: 16849
First sprite
$sprite_size: 90px;
$frames: 4;
90*4=360
starts at 0, goes to -360
percentage to translate = 360/16849*100=2.136625319
*/
@keyframes idle_pixie {
  from {
    background-position: 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 2.136625319%;
  }
}

/*
Second sprite
360+360 = 720
starts at -360, goes to -720
*/
@keyframes idle_fairy {
  from {
    background-position: 2.136625319%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 4.2732506382%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="monster monster--pixie"></div>
<div class="monster monster--fairy"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that I can have it unprefixed, @larsmagnus! I only have one other question, for the original `.monster` I am assuming that is defining all of the other monsters size, but what if some are larger than 90x90px? Not many are on the sheet, but some will be.

Comment: The size in the `.monster` class can just be considered as a default that you can override. For you to be able to scale each monster we need to translate the spritesheet based on percentages, which just requires a bit more math. I updated my answer to reflect this! :) Please consider accepting this answer if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Not sure if it's codepen but I've been having troubles getting some aligned perfectly, will try it on other sites to see. Thanks for the help! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I used a bit of jQuery to demonstrate the use of the same animation for different "monsters".
`#monster1` animates from the beginning. `#monster2` starts when the button is clicked and class `.monster` is added.

**UPDATE:**
Additional classes defined to animate another monster.

```js
$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  $("#monster2").addClass("monster2");
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.monster {
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
}

.monster1 {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/423540996098228245/494950824963866635/16x16.png");
  animation: playMonster1 .8s steps(4) infinite;
}

.monster2 {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/423540996098228245/494950824963866635/16x16.png");
  animation: playMonster2 .8s steps(4) infinite;
}

@keyframes playMonster1 {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -360px;
  }
}

@keyframes playMonster2 {
  from {
    background-position: -360px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -720px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="monster1" class="monster monster1"></div>
<div id="monster2" class="monster"></div>
<button>Start monster 2</button>
```

Comment: Hi there! Sorry if I wasn't clear, the spritesheet has more than 1 sprite on it. After the 4 frames, there are dozens more (4 per monster) that I am wanting to animate on the same page. I guess I need to put the declaration into its own class and assign names to the animations, but I have no idea how to do that and make it work with as many browsers as possible.

Comment: @Will Got it. I adjusted the code to animate another monster